# Trouble using Vault in JBoss EAP 7.0.0

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x, jboss-eap-7, passwordvault

I've been trying to remotely connect using JNDI to a JBoss server running on JBoss EAP 7, but so far I've had only trouble, and all of the tutorials I see are for EAP 6.4 or earlier.

My question is: Can EAP 7 still use Vault encryption, similar to how earlier versions did, or is it completely out-of-date?

Comment: Did you mean [this](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/vault.html) Vault?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't specific. No, I mean [this](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/JBossAS7SecuringPasswords) one, @TT.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Vault is still suported in EAP 7.
According to the documentation:  The supported sources for resolving expressions are system properties, environment variables, and the vault

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en/red-hat-jboss-enterprise-application-platform/7.0/single/configuration-guide/#property_replacement

Comment: It would be a good idea to expand a little bit on the link you added. You never know whether the link might become invalid in the future (aka linkrot).

Comment: Ok. Thanks. The idea was just share that's still supported and where its mentioned in documentation.